# In CrafterCMS drag and drop configuration is not working properly

Tags: drag-and-drop, content-management-system, freemarker

In **CrafterCMS**, I'm trying to setup the **drag and drop** facility in my current project.
But when I'm in studio I get following error message:

[image]

Despite the error, **I'm able to add new components to the page with drag and drop**, however when I add a new component, all the previous selected components are replaced by the new one.

I.e. if I have:

[image]

By adding a new "component6" I get:

[image]

Here's the template of page

```
<#import "/templates/system/common/cstudio-support.ftl" as studio />
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> 

  <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->

    <#assign siteTitle =  contentModel.title!"" />

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>${siteTitle}</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/static-assets/images/favicon.ico">

        <!--Google Font link-->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static-assets/css/animate.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static-assets/css/iconfont.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static-assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static-assets/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static-assets/css/magnific-popup.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static-assets/css/bootsnav.css">

        <!--For Plugins external css-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static-assets/css/plugins.css" />

        <!--Theme custom css-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static-assets/css/style.css">
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static-assets/css/colors/maron.css">-->

        <!--Theme Responsive css-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static-assets/css/responsive.css" />

        <!-- Scroll Indicator Bullets-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="static-assets/css/jquery.scrollindicatorbullets.css" />

        <script src="/static-assets/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar-menu" data-offset="110">

        <!-- Header -->
        <#include "/templates/web/page-home-header.ftl" />

        <!-- Sections -->
        <div <@studio.iceAttr iceGroup="sections"/> >
        <div class="sections" <@studio.componentContainerAttr target="sections" objectId=model.objectId/>>
            <#list (contentModel.sections.item)![] as aSection >
              <@renderComponent component=aSection />
            </#list>        
        </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <#include "/templates/web/page-home-footer.ftl" />

        <!-- JS includes -->

        <script src="/static-assets/js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/static-assets/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script src="/static-assets/js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
        <script src="/static-assets/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
        <script src="/static-assets/js/bootsnav.js"></script>

        <script src="/static-assets/js/plugins.js"></script>    
        <script src="/static-assets/js/main.js"></script>  

        <@studio.toolSupport/>  
    </body>
 </html>
```

This is the template of the component I'm using:

```
<#import "/templates/system/common/cstudio-support.ftl" as studio/>

<!--Dialogue section-->

<section id="dialogue" class="dialogue bg-white roomy-80" <@studio.componentAttr path=contentModel.storeUrl />>

    <#if contentModel.sectionTitle?? ><span class="scrollIndicatorTitle">${contentModel.sectionTitle}</span></#if>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="main_dialogue text-center">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h3>${contentModel.text}</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

When I add the component in the log I see:

```
INFO : org.craftercms.search.service.impl.SolrSearchService - [spbb] Delete for id:"spbb:/site/components/component6.xml" OR parentId:"spbb:/site/components/component6.xml" successful: {responseHeader={status=0,QTime=3}}
INFO : org.craftercms.search.service.impl.SolrSearchService - [spbb] Update for spbb:/site/components/component6.xml successful: {responseHeader={status=0,QTime=3}}
INFO : org.craftercms.search.service.impl.SolrSearchService - [spbb] Commit successful: {responseHeader={status=0,QTime=24}}
[INFO] 2017-05-09 12:25:44,716 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] [spbb] [rest.SiteCacheRestController] | Content cache and Freemarker cache have been cleared for site 'spbb'
INFO : org.craftercms.search.service.impl.SolrSearchService - [spbb] Delete for id:"spbb:/site/website/products/index.xml" OR parentId:"spbb:/site/website/products/index.xml" successful: {responseHeader={status=0,QTime=7}}
WARN : org.craftercms.search.service.impl.RenameFieldsIfMultiValuePostProcessor - Field 'sections.item.component.createdDate_dt' is declared as single value, but multiple values where provided in spbb:/site/website/products/index.xml. Renaming to multi value field 'sections.item.component.createdDate_dts'
WARN : org.craftercms.search.service.impl.RenameFieldsIfMultiValuePostProcessor - Field 'sections.item.component.lastModifiedDate_dt' is declared as single value, but multiple values where provided in spbb:/site/website/products/index.xml. Renaming to multi value field 'sections.item.component.lastModifiedDate_dts'
INFO : org.craftercms.search.service.impl.SolrSearchService - [spbb] Update for spbb:/site/website/products/index.xml successful: {responseHeader={status=0,QTime=7}}
INFO : org.craftercms.search.service.impl.SolrSearchService - [spbb] Commit successful: {responseHeader={status=0,QTime=29}}
[INFO] 2017-05-09 12:25:45,174 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] [spbb] [rest.SiteCacheRestController] | Content cache and Freemarker cache have been cleared for site 'spbb'
```

**There's something else that I'm missing?**